# determine position of matching word within a regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

**Situation:**

I have a static dictionary and a dynamically determined regular expression.

The regular expression is somewhat limited in it's application here in that I would never use symbols that stand for a variable number of characters.

I need to create a regular expression that finds all words in the dictionary that match this type of pattern: `(any letter in set: q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i or blank) & (any letter in set: q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i or blank) & (a or blank) & (s or blank) & (and letter in set: q,w or blank) & (d or blank) & (any letter in set: q,w,e or blank)`

```
[q,e,r,t,y,u,i,null][q,e,r,t,y,u,i,null][a,null][s,null][q,w,null][d,null][q,w,e,null]
```

For example the word "rasw" would be valid (assuming it's in my dictionary).

**Problem:**

I also need one more piece of information, I need to know that this word started in the 2nd position. As apposed to the also valid word "qra" which starts in the first position or the valid word "sqde" which starts in the 4th position.

**Additional Info:**

I plan on doing this in MS SQL SERVER using a regular expression .dll
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/SqlRegEx.aspx

Also note that given the above example I would not want "qqqq" to be a valid word even if it was in the dictionary. The word would not be allowed to skip over a space, however it is allowed to not start on the first space if this makes scene and is possible to do...

Thanks!

Comment: When you say starts in 'xth' position do you mean the position in the regex that the match begins?

Comment: @Mark - yes  this is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would very strongly suggest using CLR here. Then in .NET do your regex stuff. And if you find the word, all you need to do is to do a `.Split(" ")` on spaces, and then iterrate through the array and find out the n'th position it is in.

For example: `var myString = "The fat fox is lazy";`
(assume you matches the word "is") - so you know that "is" is in there, now to figure out the location you can:

```
var _counter = 0;
foreach(var s as string in myString.Split(" "))
{
if(s == "is") { return _counter; }

_counter += 1;
}
```

Hope you get the idea of what I am suggesting here.